# Plotly ticks are weirdly aligned

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Let's take the following `pd.DataFrame` as an example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'month': ['2022-01', '2022-02', '2022-03'],
    'col1': [1_000, 1_500, 2_000],
    'col2': [100, 150, 200],
}).melt(id_vars=['month'], var_name='col_name')
```

which creates

```
    month   col_name    value
-----------------------------
0   2022-01 col1        1000
1   2022-02 col1        1500
2   2022-03 col1        2000
3   2022-01 col2        100
4   2022-02 col2        150
5   2022-03 col2        200
```

Now when I would use simple seaborn

```
sns.barplot(data=df, x='month', y='value', hue='col_name');
```

I would get:

[image]

Now I would like to use [plotly](https://plotly.com/) and the following code

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.histogram(df, 
                   x="month", 
                   y="value",
                   color='col_name', barmode='group', height=500, width=1_200)
fig.show()
```

And I get:

[image]

So why are the x-ticks so weird and not simply `2022-01`, `2022-02` and `2022-03`?

What is happening here?

I found that I always have this problem with the ticks when using `color`. It somehow messes the ticks up.

Comment: This is the default display of plotly, so the following methods will be used to achieve the intended format. `fig.update_layout(xaxis_tickformat='%Y-%m')` See this:[https://plotly.com/python/time-series/](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/)

Comment: I've experimented with tick formats too, and found that the second group's x-tick label still includes January; but the hovertext correctly displays February. Perhaps the issue lies in the inner workings of datetime-xlabel-handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by customizing the step as 1 month per tick with `dtick="M1",` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'month': ['2022-01', '2022-02', '2022-03'],
    'col1': [1000, 1500, 2000],
    'col2': [100, 150, 200],
}).melt(id_vars=['month'], var_name='col_name')


fig = px.bar(df, 
                   x="month", 
                   y="value",
                   color='col_name', barmode='group', height=500, width=1200)


fig.update_xaxes(
                tickformat = '%Y-%m',   
                dtick="M1",
        )

fig.show()
```

[image]